# Code is running but I am not in that component - Angular

Tags: angular, service, components, running-other-programs

I set an interval in the admin component to check for new messages.
but when I logged out then I noticed that the interval method is still running.

```
setInterval(() => {
   this.service.checkNew();
}, 300);

// Code
checkNew() {
  this.http.get(this.basic.url + 'checknew/').subscribe((res) => {
    if (res['data'].length) {
      let sound = new Audio();
      sound.src = this.basic.static += 'sounds/alert.wav';
      sound.play();
      for (let item of res['data']) {
        if (this.contacts.length) {
          this.getItem('contacts/' + item.id + '/').then((message) => {
            this.contacts.unshift(<any>message);
          });
        }
        this.messages += 1;
        this.basic.fireAlert(item['name'] + ' Send message', 4);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Check network section of console in image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/18zpu.png

Comment: setInterval run in global scope if I'm not mistaken, you need to clear the interval when you leave the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with subscriptions, those callbacks aren't destroyed when you exit the compontent.

So you need to store the reference to the interval when creating it:

```
this.checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
   this.service.checkNew();
}, 300);
```

and add [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) in `ngOnDestroy` to destroy it when your component is destroyed:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.checkInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using setInterval for polling is a very bad idea. `setInterval` doesn't care about the previous call, if for some reason your server slows down you will end up enqueuing requests until your server crashes.
instead of that i recommend you using `RxJs`

```
const fakeAsyncWork = (index) => of(index).pipe(delay(10 * index))
let index = 1;
defer(() => fakeAsyncWork(index))
  .pipe(repeatWhen((res) => res.pipe(delay(100))))
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res + ' fake async took: ' + 10 * index + 'ms to perform');
    index = index + 5;
  });
```

This way you can ensure, that a delay will be respected between each call. To release the subscription you can call to unsubscribe on the `ngOnDestroy` or use this library https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy